# Method error in retrieving multiple values from sql in a web service

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web-services

I'm new to web service. I'm experimenting on how to retrieve more than 1 value from a sql query in a web service. I tried with some tutorial and below is my attempt. I know I'm nearly there but when I debug the following code. There is no error in the code but the method did not appear on the web service at all. Please help and tell me what is exactly wrong or should there be another approach of doing this?

```
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {

            public class Record
            {
                public int userid { get; set; }
                public string username { get; set; }
                public string city { get; set; }
                public int age { get; set; }

            }

            [WebMethod]
            public static List<Record> GetData(int age)
            {
                age = 1;

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DIT-NB1260382;Initial Catalog=Experiment;Integrated Security=True");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT userid, username, city, age FROM userdet where age = '" + age + "'", con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                List<Record> records = new List<Record>();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    records.Add(new Record()
                    {
                        userid = dr.GetInt32(0),
                        username = dr.GetString(1),
                        city = dr.GetString(2),
                        age = dr.GetInt32(3),

                    });
                }

                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
                return records;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Method does not appear at all when I debug the web service]

Comment: you have records in your db `where age = 1`? And what is not working because this code looks fine to me.

Comment: no. age is going to be a parameter. I just declare an int before executing sql query.

Comment: Lookup how to use command parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx  and it is still not clear to me what isn't working

Comment: You may want to look up how `using`-blocks work, on exceptions, your code will leak handles.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `[WebService]` attribute at your class definition...

Comment: guess. @Grant Winney is right. I pass the age as string. I changed according to what you stated. Thanks!, the method appears now.